# How to ask for a boolean input from a user to qualify if statements and print a sentence using that information in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

I'm here with my first (hopefully not last) query for you.

I'm trying to get information from the user, specifically boolean values to determine if they are male/female and tall/short, then print the correct statement of "You are a tall/short male/female"

```
is_tall = input("Are you tall?")
is_male = input("Are you male?")

if is_tall and is_male:
  print("You are a tall male")
elif is_tall and not(is_male):
  print("You are a tall female")
elif not(is_tall) and is_male:
  print("You are a short male, sorry")
else:
  print("You are a short female, sorry")
```

My code runs and always returns "You are a tall male", searching reveals this is because the user's input is considered always true as it is a string.

I've seen other examples for grabbing boolean values but not for grabbing two and using them both within if statements. Am I anywhere close here, what am I missing? I know I can't use bool() around the input to convert it.

Comment: what does the user types as an answer? what are the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
tall_str = input("Are you tall? ")
while tall_str.lower() not in {'y', 'yes', 'n', 'no'}:
   tall_str = input("Are you tall [y/n] ? ")

is_tall = True if tall_str.lower() in {'y', 'yes'} else False
```

this will accept things like `'Yes'` and `'nO'` (for `tall_str`) and then convert them to `True` or `False` (for `is_tall`) and ask again if the given answer is not acceptable.

you could then do the same for `is_male`.

having cast the string to a boolean your `if` clauses will work.

Comment: Thank you! I'll work on learning the bits in here I didn't know, you've got it working brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are checking if the string is non-zero.  Instead, check the value of the string.

```
    if is_tall.upper() in ('YES', 'Y') and is_male.upper() in ('YES', 'Y'):
        print("You are a tall male")
    elif is_tall.upper() in ('YES', 'Y') and is_male.upper() in ('NO', 'N'):
        print("You are a tall female")
```

etc.

You may list as many valid strings (answers) as you like in the brackets after `in`, and forcing all input to either `.upper()` or `.lower()` saves you from dealing with twice as many (or more) possible responses.

Comment: Thank you! Together with hiro you both got this working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Would this approach seem fit to you?

```
is_tall = True if input("Are you tall?").lower() == 'y' else False
is_male = True if input("Are you male?").lower() == 'y' else False
...
```

There is no easy way to get bool in input, although you can convert it yourself.

Comment: As Hiro suggests, you can also augment these conditions like
if input("Are you male?") in ['y', 'yes', 'ya', 'yos'] else False